# How do you make an animal spawner in Minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want some sheep, cows, and pigs for a farm but they all died and I have nothing but chickens. How do I make a room or a place that quickly spawns animals? I want wool, milk, and meat but can't get any of them because there are no animals. How do I make an animal spawner in Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but you can't do anything, animals in minecraft spawn in packs and if you killed the whole pack the spawn will be lost in that certain area. **Next time be friendly to mother nature.**

Comment: Up vote for silliness. :P

Comment: Also, if you could somehow lead another pack into the area, that might work.

Comment: GG you are crazy doooood

Comment: I think you mean Crayzee* ♥

Comment: Hahahahahaha LOL

Answer (score 0):

You could find two of the animal, and lead them to your house or the room you will put them in, and then feed them until hearts come out of both of them. Then a baby will spawn, and you can keep breeding as many times as you like. You just need to figure out what the animal you are trying to breed eats.

Comment: A little challenge to make this answer better: Add **what** it needs to eat.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get animals is to build an animal breeder. Just put 2 of the same mob into a fenced off area, and keep breeding them. You have to wait 1 minute before you can breed them again, but the animals multiply very fast using this method. Place a carpet on the fence gate to allow yourself to get in and out easily.